# Unable to start Neo4j on Windows, no error messages

Tags: java, neo4j

I'm using the following on Windows 7:

- neo4j-community-1.9.2
- Java 7 Update 25

I have Windows Firewall disabled.

When I start Neo4j.bat, both as Administrator and normally, I get the following message:

```
c:\Tools\neo4j\bin>Neo4j.bat 
28/07/13 9:34:27 PM org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer INFO: Setting startup tim 
eout to: 120000ms based on -1
```

A blank Java console window pops up, no messages, then the window disappears after a minute or so.

When I go to `http://localhost:7474/`, I just get a server not found error.

If I try to install it as a service, the service wouldn't start.

Any ideas what I need to do to start Neo4j? I see here that Neo4j 1.9 does support Java 7:

http://blog.neo4j.org/2013/03/neo4j-19m05-released-wrapping-up.html

`base.bat` correctly points to `windows-service-wrapper-5.jar`, so not the `windows-service-wrapper-*.jar` problem that some people have had in the past. It would be helpful if it outputted an error message.

---

I just tried it with neo4j 2.0 milestone, and it didn't make any difference. The Java window pops up with no messages, `http://localhost:7474/` gets a server not found error, then the Java window closes after a minute or two.

I added JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME system variables, made no difference. I think I would get an error if Neo4j was not able to locate Java anyway.

Comment: Could you try running `neo4j.bat console` for some output?

Comment: running with console parameter gives me the same output. i.e. org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer INFO: Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've fixed it.

With help from Neo4j's Google Group, I looked at the logs in `data/logs/*.log` and `data/graph.db/messages.log`, and found the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 1337; nested exception is:
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
```

Once I disabled my other service that uses that port, Neo4j's web admin at `http://localhost:7474` worked. I then found out port 1337 is used by Neo4j's remote shell, I disabled it by adding `enable_remote_shell = false` to `neo4j.properties`, then I was able to have both Neo4j and my other service running.

Comment: data/logs/*.log is a relative patch - where do I find it?

Comment: I found it in the folder where I installed neo4j, in this case c:\Tools\neo4j.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the version 2.2.1 community edition of Neo4j on Windows 7, Java 1.8 update 45

In my case the log file ***messages.log*** was under ***default.graphdb*** directory. In there, you'll see the root cause of the problem.